# after splitting Chunks in webpack unable to run app

Tags: reactjs, optimization, webpack, webpack-4, html-webpack-plugin

in my react app i'm using webpack 4,before implementing split chunk everything is working fine but after `splitChunks` it generating `vendor.js` file and it showing on html file also but page is blank.
my **webpack** file

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackMd5Hash = require('webpack-md5-hash');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
const VENDOR_LIBS =[
  'antd','axios','moment','rc-time-picker','react',
  'react-dom','react-ga','react-google-maps','react-loadable',
  'react-redux','react-router','react-router-dom','recompose','redux','redux-thunk'
];
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
    entry:{
      vendor: VENDOR_LIBS,
      main: './src/app.js',
    },
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
      filename: '[name].chunkhash.bundle.js',
      chunkFilename: '[name].chunkhash.bundle.js',
    },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
          }
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use:  ['style-loader', MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            },{
                test: /\.(gif|svg|jpg|png|ttf|eot|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
                loader: "file-loader",
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'style.[contenthash].css',
            }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: false,
      hash: true,
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html'
            }),
    new WebpackMd5Hash(),
    new CompressionPlugin({
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test : /\.js$|\.css$|\.eot?.+$|\.ttf?.+$|\.woff?.+$|\.svg?.+$/,
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
      }),
    ],
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          chunks: 'initial',
          name: 'vendor',
          test: 'vendor',
          enforce: true
        },
      }
    },
    runtimeChunk: true,
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        sourceMap: true
      }),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ],
  },
};
```

and *in* my **/src/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks.main.css %>">
    <title>Book Ambulance - Stanplus</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="app">

    </div>
    <script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks.main.entry %>"></script>
    <script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks.vendor.entry %>"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

you can that those files are loading in browser but page is blank
[image]
*i have to questions*
**a)** why my app not showing nothing even not any error(**may be something in output,`splitChunks` or in `html` page**).
**b)** after doing `UglifyJsPlugin`,`CompressionPlugin` and dynamically adding routes and import libs/files but also **my vendor.js file size is 580 KB**,except all these techniques **how can i reduce the size of my vendor.js file**

Comment: remove those script tags, let HtmlWebpackPlugin insert it by itself. So we can see what is going on

Comment: @PlayMa256 do you mean,`new HtmlWebpackPlugin()` like this

Comment: yeah it is dynamically adding scripts but it showing me ** Uncaught Error: Minified React error #200**,i already mention `webpack --mode production`

Comment: add DefinePlugin to set NODE_ENV to production too, that might fix your last error with react minified

Comment: @PlayMa256 actually `inject: false` changed to  `inject: true` ,so every thing is working fine but still my **vendor.js** size **577 KB** so how i can reduce vendor size.

Comment: use bundle-analyzer to see what is big, and try to clear that up.

Comment: I had this problem with a similar issue - I'm referencing the built `.bundle.js` file directly in a Razor View. Normally the HtmlWebpackPlugin would automatically include what's needed for this bundle to work but with `optimization.splitChunks.chunks = 'all'` it was splitting critical code (e.g. React) to a separate .js file and the page wouldn't run. I fixed this by changing chunks back to `async`.